# Submitting a form using JavaScript and image maps

Tags: javascript, image, xhtml

I have a issue, I have a form called quicksearch

CODE

```
<form method="GET" name="quicksearch" action="search_results.php">

            <input name="search" type="text" id="search" size="50" value="<?=@$_REQUEST['search']?>">

        </form>
```

The submit button is an image map

and looks as follows

```
<img src="images/header_16.jpg" alt="" width="111" height="42" border="0" usemap="#Map3">
```

How can I submit this using javascript, I have the following but it fails everytime and does nothing.

```
<map name="Map3">

  <area shape="rect" coords="2,4,109,39" href="javascript:document.quicksearch.submit();">

</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

This should submit the first form on the page.

Or even give the form an id and use this:

```
document.getElementById('formID').submit();
```